# How `Projections.max("registrationNo")` will work when registrationNo is String

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an entity called `StudentDetails`.In that there is a field `RegistrationNo` of type String.My client follows a pattern like xxxxx-xxxx (Number in sequence 00000 To 10000)-(current Year Number).To Store `RegistrationNo` in this pattern we declared it as String.Every time new student is joined we have to increment the sequence number we have to store it.

I tried  Without knowing that it stored as String i tried to fetch last number using `Projections.max("registrationNo")` Luckily it returned max number i don't know how.But still again problem raised when sequence number reached 6 digits like xxxxxx-xxxx then `Projections.max("registrationNo")` is *not* returning 6 digit number.It is returning only max of 5 digit number .

**How projection is returning max of 5 digit number but not 6 digit number**.

by the way i solved that problem using id of the record to know last `RegistrationNo`.But `Projections.max("registrationNo")` is puzzling me on how it worked for sometime.

Comment: If your property is a string (which I assume it is due to the formatting) `max` will do a string comparison. So `1000000` will be smaller than `2`, since `1 < 2`.

Comment: @Thomas then how 01000 will be greater than 00002 ..??

Comment: That's because `1 > 0`. String comparisons will compare characters, i.e. if you compare `010` and `002` it will actually compare `0` and `0` then `1` and `0` and since those are different, comparison will stop.

Comment: oh..got it..when number of digits are same it will work .if number of digit changes then it won't work..Thanks..Post your comment as answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments the problem is most likely a string comparison, i.e. calling `max()` on a property of type string will result in the "maximum" string value being returned, even if those strings represent numbers.

A string comparison is normally done by comparing characters from start to end until there is a difference or the end of one input string is reached (in which case the longer string would be the greater one).

Thus as long as your sequence numbers are of equal length it should work since comparing `10000` and `00001` will result in the "correct" characters being compared.

However, once the string lengths are different, a normal string compare won't work anymore, since the characters do represent different digits. Hence comparing `98765` to `123456` will result in `98765` being greater since the first characters to be compared will be  `1` and `9` and `1 < 9` almost all of the time (unless you changed that somehow).

To solve this you can take a couple of routes which depend on your environment and goals:

- store the sequence number in a separate numeric property
- make the sequence strings longer right from the start, i.e. allow for a bigger range
- add a specialized comparator in the code or the database (just as a hint, I'd have to look up how to do it)

From a performance point of view I'd probably take the first route.